# updating an object from another view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone view (ItemDetailedView) which container another view (ShopItemDetailedView). Inside the ShopItemDetailed view I have an img that when clicked it needs to updates the ItemDetailed model. In other words it needs to call fetch on the ItemDetailed model. How can I do this on the ShopItemDetailed? I was thinking of passing the item model to the shop model and then set the id of the item. However I dont think that this is a good solution as it is against the decoupling principle. Here's some code on my ShopItemDetailedView

```
 loadNewItem: function(itemid) {
        //i want to change set the item id here that is on ItemDetailedView
    },
```

I was thinking of the publisher and subscriber method, such that on this event I would publish an event that sends the new id of the item it should fetch. Not sure on how to do that though

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
window.EVENT_BUS = {};

_.extend(EVENT_BUS, Backbone.Events);

// inside ShopItemDetailed click handler
EVENT_BUS.trigger('ShopItemDetailedClick', {id: 'foo'});

// inside ItemDetailedView initialize
EVENT_BUS.on('ShopItemDetailedClick', function (args) {
    console.log('do something with ', args.id);
});
```

Comment: is there any backbone.js specific solution?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally if the `ShopItemDetailedView` will have the subscriber role and `ItemDetailedView` will have an observer role you can trigger a view event:

```
loadNewItem: function(itemid) {
    this.trigger('itemShop');
}
```

And subscribe `ItemDetailedView` to the `ShopItemDetailedView`'s itemShop event

```
ItemDetailedView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        shopItemDetailedViewInstance.on('itemShop', this.itemShop);
    },
    itemShop : function(){
        //your observer code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Of course look at this example of triggering custom model events
http://jsbin.com/OwUnOGo/1/